# Using google analytics for self hosted , offline web app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, google-analytics

I have a web app which is self hosted by customers.
It is designed for offline use and `connects to the internet rarely ,sometimes NOT FOR WEEKS`.
The app runs AngularJS on frontend and Nodejs on backend.

I would like to track customer behaviour in the client side - which buttons he clicks, how much time he spends on a page etc.

How do I go about implementing this ?
Is google analytics suitable for this use case ?  [The website speaks about using service workers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/offline-google-analytics)  , is this suitable for my case ?

Comment: Were you able to find an answer for this? It looks like Google Analytics may work but it has some limitations, such as a time limit on how long it can accurately report offline hits (https://www.quantable.com/analytics/google-analytics-data-processing-schedule/).

Comment: No. Did not get time to investigate , had to put this in the back burner. I shall take a look, thanks.